# Posting a dynamically changed textarea value doesn't work with ajax forms

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on a browser extension (google chrome and firefox) which uses content script to change a textarea value. I'm working with this script:

On google chrome I use this script :

```
function print(msg, textarea){
  textarea.focus();
  textarea.click();
  textarea.value = '';
  for(var i=0; i<msg.length;i++){
    var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
    e.initKeyboardEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 0, msg.charCodeAt(i));
    textarea.dispatchEvent(e);
    textarea.value += msg[i];
  }
}
```

On some websites using AJAX the value of the textarea is correctly updated but for some reasons when I submit the form, the old textarea content is posted instead. If I **manually** press one key, the problem is solved.

I can't understand where the problem is. I tried $(textarea).keydown().keypress().keyup().change() or .blur() with jQuery but it didn't help.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how content scripts work on Chrome - on Firefox with the SDK you may need to use the 'unsafeWindow' object to access the textarea directly after JS code in the window makes changes to it.

Comment: It might be a good idea to give a link to "some websites" (or, even better, a reduced version of their code). They probably copy the text area value into a hidden field that they submit - and often this is done listening to the `keyup` event.

Comment: @canuckistani: This code uses DOM methods and properties only, proxies shouldn't be an issue. Btw, content scripts in Chrome work very similarly (only "real" DOM properties and methods are accessible), only that Chrome doesn't offer any way around this protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wladimir is right, the issue is often about a hidden field and the keyup event.
The triggering order is the key. I believe a correct way is :

```
for(var i=0; i<msg.length;i++){
  var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
  e.initKeyboardEvent("keydown", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 0, msg.charCodeAt(i));
  textarea.dispatchEvent(e);

  var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
  e.initKeyboardEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 0, msg.charCodeAt(i));
  textarea.dispatchEvent(e);

  textarea.value += msg[i];

  var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
  e.initKeyboardEvent("keyup", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 0, msg.charCodeAt(i));
  textarea.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

It worked on firefox and google chrome (but firefox uses initKeyEvent instead of initKeyboardEvent)